# What are the different areas or compartment would a colony-ship have?

Tags: science-based, spaceships, generation-ships, shipbuilding

So I'm trying to create a sci-fi colony ship for a science discussion that we have in class. So as a sci-fi fan (Hard sci-fi to be exact), I want to portray a realistic ship and not those cliche spaceships we know when we were kids.

[image: Ship Example]

So you see those 2 gravitation rings right? An area in which we would have to artificially mimic the effect of gravity to replicate gravity on earth for work and stuff like that. So looking at those rings, each probably contains more than 6 sectors each.

Since colonists will have to sleep, So there would be something like a hotel sector, and a park sector for recrational activities, A cafeteria sector for crews to eat in, as its not like we have to eat while floating, and of course is a laboratory sector for space reasearch stuff, and also the command deck where controls are commanded, and the engineering section for fixes.

So my question is: What other sectors or compartments is needed?

Since i just started learning about the physics of these ships, Im just asking or some help in portraying a realistic take for this.

Comment: When a question is put on hold, edit it to have it reopen. Don't post another one while deleting the old one.

Comment: Also please read the tag description before using them. You used hard science, but it requires scientific evidences which we simply lack for the design of a generation ship. The tag has been replaced by science based.

Comment: For a start, think about the inputs to your home, and the outputs from your home, and follow those chains. For example, you will need to reprocess air, to store extra air (you brought some along, right?), to test air, to analyze air problems, to reprocess water, to process sewage, to store extra water, to dispose of reprocessing output, to test clean water, to analyze water problems. Etc for food, clothing, health and medicine and maternity, schooling, medicine, corpse processing, culture, economy, law enforcement, politics, defense, transport, and much much more.

Comment: A science module wouldn't neccesarrily be in the ring. The ability to control level of environmental centrifugal pull would be a huge bonus to science work (from zero to well beyond normal) which you *don't* want tied to living quarters. And ignoring that, makes more sense to have science done in a weightless area as that removes a variable.

Further note: Rings may be neccesarry for a station or intrasolar ship to have gravity, but not neccesarry for an interstellar ship: Constant Acceleration/Deceleration can easily take care of that with fewer moving parts

Comment: What is the scale of this ship? Layout requirements will be different if you have 1,000 or 10,000 or 100,000 population.

Comment: @liljoshu Constant 1g acceleration (or even a more conservative .5g) for the span of hundreds if not thousands of years would be astounding. It would increase the fuel requirements to truly astronomical levels. Maintaining the spin on a habitat ring is comparatively negligible. Constant acceleration would require an unobtanium reactionless drive, at which point you may as well just say "magic".

Answer (score 2):

In general we're moving around from "sectors" like that. If you have a shopping sector and an industrial sector and a housing sector then you end up with people commuting and travelling which is wasteful of both energy and time.

Instead integrated communities with local shops, schools, offices and houses are much more likely - with each having the required mix of facilities.

Especially in a long-term colony ship you can expect it to be set up to resemble a "normal" life as much as possible, so homes with people cooking their own food would be just as common as people eating at a communal cafeteria.

The one thing that might have "zones" would be areas set aside for recreation (parks), wildlife, or environmental purposes such as oxygenation or food production (although hydroponics would likely be important for both of those things).

Comment: Aside from separating industrial activity for safety, hard segregation of areas types does seem weird, almost as weird as individuals cooking. When mass and energy are significant challenges for a generation ship, putting a full kitchen in every dwelling (even the concept of individual dwellings) seems extremely archaic. Shops, offices, houses, and cooking at home are all akin to 1950's thinking that society a thousand years in the future will still be structured around a nuclear family with traditional gender roles.

Answer (score 1):

A colony ship, which may or may not be part of a fleet, should resemble an artificial space habitat in the areas not filled with the engines and fuel supply and other spaceship features.

The longer the journey - such as an interstellar journey with slower than light drive - and the more years, decades, or centuries the voyage may take, the larger the inhabited parts of the ship will be and the more the ship will resemble a space colony in a space habitat with a spaceship attached for propulsion.

So it might be a good idea to study several designs for space habitats and decide which features make sense in a presumably interstellar colony ship traveling for years, decades, or centuries to its destination.

The use of giant windows and mirrors to illuminate a space habitat orbiting the Sun at Earth's distance would probably not make much sense in an interstellar voyage where the natural light from the stars might be only a millionth as bright, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Modular main chamber + navigation + hygeine + likely very small personal chambers + growing chamber.

A common mistake is that people try to treat colony ships like flying houses or skyscrapers. A closer (but still not quite there comparison) is an early colony sailing ship with the realization that it doesn't have a world to support it.

Most boats had a main room and a main deck for daily activities depending on whether the weather was nice enough to be inside and outside. It's hard vacuum outside, so the purpose of two main areas is removed, leaving only one. Navigation needs to be seperate purely so day-to-day activities don't interfere with navigation consoles. Since a lot would be automated, probably doesn't need to be very big, but you'd want it because in an emergency, you want to have manual controls if modifying flight plans on a tablet is unworkable for some reason (like power outage). Personal rooms are needed because people snore and they want to store their personal possessions. Depending on space requirements, these may be only a personal locker, and a seperate set of enclosed bunk areas that people switch out of. Otherwise, the main area would likely be adapted to whatever needs are currently needed. People want privacy when on the privvy and you don't want stuff flying around, so they'd probably be seperate. As for growing, plants are kinda messy (parts break off, wilt, decompose, drop fruit, there's juices, etc.) and have special needs (lots of light panels, hydration, nutrients, all automated as much as possible).

Additional potential "messy"/specialty rooms that may warrent their own compartments depending on size of ship:

- red light area
- cooking
- emergency response equipment (medical, hull breaches, fires, etc.), likely placed near center of hub for fast access
- surgery
- armory
- chemical processing
- 3D printing enclosures

Also worth noting that these are just *physical* containers. As incorporating VR, AR, into the structure is highly likely due to it's benefits of space efficiency, VR spaces are likely to constantly be created for various purposes (and may or may not have dedicated space for those using them, possibly incorporated into personal spaces).

Comment: Also worth pointing out, that many places will double-up on purposes or be multi-purpose. Unless there's a *very* good reason, most things won't have dedicated areas. Surgery makes sense due to sterility requirements, armory for danger of the materials stored, etc. But when you have a communal enclosed environment where space is a premium, separation of many things into their own areas doesn't make sense.

Comment: This shows a lot of cultural bias. Privacy on the privy? Ancient Romans thought the toilets were great places to socialize, and they were not alone in that. Why have a "red light area"? Puritan morality which should not be assumed for such a culture as would arise on a generation ship. Snoring indicates a medical problem which should be fixed, so not an issue. Lockers are needed if you think people are going to steal your stuff... where are they going to take it? And for that matter, what stuff?

Comment: @pluckedkiwi The author asked for a realistic scenario. As it stands, all the current space-faring nations likely to leave their mark in spacefaring culture are more puritan. Honestly, it'd make more sense from a logical direction that in a climate controlled environment that clothes would be abandoned altogether. Even at the current ridiculous cost of sending stuff up into orbit, however, our space agencies have still left their astronauts wearing clothes. So likely, some traditions will remain.

As for privies remaining private, there's a legitimate reason there, and that's...

Comment: ... all the liquids involved (both by the person and any by the privy). To put simply, you don't want liquids getting out of a controlled environment and rusting things they shouldn't, shorting things they shouldn't, etc. As for a red light area... again, bodily fluids, plus many people have different preferences so a simple open area doesn't quite work. People may think it may be relegated to people's own quarters, but even though it's claimed people work that way, we really don't, but we try to maintain appearances. And for sleeping, snoring was just one example, people have many preferences

Comment: As for lockers, whether or not people steal, fear of theft is common (and whether something could be hidden is impacted by the size of the station). The lack of the ability to keep anything "secure" or "private" would give any ship's counselor way more overtime hours than they could handle.

Comment: The privy response makes no sense - why would you need complete privacy "in order to contain liquids"? Do you think there is only a binary choice between entirely private individual stalls and just pissing on the floor in the central corridor? I didn't say there would be no toilets - those are still obvious - what I disagree with is that they would spend valuable space and weight on putting up single stalls for privacy as if the need to use a toilet was such an inherently shameful thing that we should all pretend nobody poops. It is silly.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi For one, as mentioned, it's unrealistic to think that societal norms will completely disappear. Our current astronauts wear clothes in space even though it's not needed, and their toilets are private despite space and cost being even more of a commodity. For second, for a practical social reason, it stinks. You don't want your entire spaceship smelling like poop. For third, for a practical mechanical reason, you want liquids contained on your spaceship. Bathrooms sealed, water in containers, etc. Because moisture condensation fries  circuits, and fried circuits means dead ship.

Comment: That sex has to be restricted to a specific area out of sight else all surfaces will be somehow covered in ejaculate... that is absurd. Obviously if someone wants to have a loud screaming orgasm session, then yes they should go somewhere more private, but that is just common courtesy to others no different than if you are having an angry screaming argument or singing karaoke. As far as preferences go, are you implying gay sex should be forced into the back alleys as nobody should see it? That is kinda offensive.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi No. By preferences I didn't mean preferences in gender, I meant preferences in tools and kink. Again, free-floating liquids need contained on a spaceship. And if your preferences are messy, they need to be contained.

Comment: Clothes are both protective and assist in hygiene - they are not just for modesty. And current astronauts are very much fully integrated into current society - a generation ship would be an entirely different environment with its own cultural norms. That they demand absolute privacy when using a toilet should not be assumed. I'm not saying do away with toilets, and I'm not saying toilets have to be in the middle of a corridor, but that it is somehow a fundamental part of human nature that there needs to be absolute privacy when using a toilet is purely a cultural assumption.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi You're not getting the point. The problem isn't privacy (although even a generation ship's culture isn't made from nothing, it will come from existing cultures.) The problem is open-air liquids. Showers, baths, etc. will also not be a thing. You obviously are underestimating the impact condensation has. Because, again, liquids. Hygiene will likely all be suction based. What liquids there are will likely be recycled for cooling systems and/or drinking to then be recycled again. In a spaceship, a water main bursting is more dangerous than a fire.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi Anyone who owns a boat knows the havoc high moisture content in the air wrecks on a boat. The problem for a spaceship is ten-fold that because instead of being able to be drydocked every two years to get serviced with new materials and fix ruined connectors, you're looking at literally generations without new materials. Airborne moisture is a major enemy in this scenario.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi You need sealed privies to contain the liquids, and allow hosing up any accidents before it's opened. And a sealed privy means either it's private or the walls are all see-through. And as transparent materials are more expensive, and existing cultural norms are for privacy, there's literally no reason they wouldn't be private. Even a fully exhibitionist culture would likely make them private for practical reasons.